# My PC Always Hangs Whenever I'll watch an online video or even start video chat

Tags: windows, video, freeze

My PC has recently started hanging completely whenever I start online video or video chat. Nothing works, even tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and mouse does not respond, leaving me only one option of hard reboot. I changed my monitor recently. Don't know whether it is the cause of the problem.

I have Windows XP SP3
1GB of RAM
NVIDIA Quadro PCI-E Series videocard
Dell 1907FP monitor
CPU is 3.0GHz

Comment: er... this isn't a programming question.

Comment: it's not even a real question

Comment: try replacing the discombobulator with higher rated one; preferably a blue one....

Comment: you've got sality virus..

Answer (score 2):

There are three possiblities:

1. It is a driver problem. Either reinstall your existing drivers for you video card or see if there are updated ones.
2. The video card is overheating. Check to make sure all cooling fans are spinning and keep objects from blocking the vents in the case.
3. The video card is damaged. You now have an excuse to buy an upgrade.

I seriously doubt that the monitor caused the freezing. If you tried the first two suggestions but you're still not convinced it's the card itself, you can try troubleshooting more scenarios. Does it freeze when watching dvds or video files stored on the hard drive? Does it freeze when you play video games? Does it freeze with only certain applications or any video player? Some times multimedia apps or video games use features of a video card that haven't been tested well enough and can leave it in a funky state after the program is no longer running.

Comment: you forgot to mention dusting out the system.